# WPF, WCF Security using ASP.Net Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wpf, wcf

I am building an application that has a WCF service that a WPF and ASP.Net MVC client will connect to.

I want to use the ASP.Net Membership providers for authentication for both the MVC and WPF clients.

What is the best way to go about this?  I have read a number of articles on-line (see below) and tried following them through but keep running into errors.

- http://www.nablasoft.com/alkampfer/index.php/2009/09/08/use-aspnet-membership-provider-with-a-wcf-svc-service/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx

Comment: what errors do you keep running into? Whats the hurdle? The certificates?

Comment: Yea it seems to be mainly certificates that are causing the problem.
Will log the errors when I am on the machine with the code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking this [CodePlex WCF Security Link](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurityGuide), it provides a number of scenarios with pretty complete checklists for the configuration of the security setup. Hopefully there will be a scenario that will be close to yours that you can go through and check things against.